# NGROK Error when trying to host Minecraft server (closed)

Tags: tcp, minecraft, ngrok

I know this isn't exactly a programming issue. However, I'm trying to have some fun with friends and host a Minecraft server. Whenever I try to portforward using "ngrok tcp 25565" which always worked for me, it says "internal server error

ERR_NGROK_802"

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ngrok is down.   It's not just you, it's our whole team.